# How to set custom post structure in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking for code block to change image tumbnail position in WordPress theme folder.
The position what I want is , I want image tumbail is left side of Same div.row and Post's Title and Entry will be Right side of same "div.row" Element. I just want to know how to set it."

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <img src="images/myimage.png" alt="" titl="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo2">
    <div class="bar2">
      <h1 class="mytitle">What am I doing?</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <a>Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should use "How to set custom post structure" instead of current of question.

Comment: Have you tried to add `float: left` to the `foo` div ?